# change data of a column for unique id and min, max date

Tags: pandas, date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC2Qc.png)

```
   id    date       source
   456   01-05-2019    AQ
   456   02-05-2019    AQ
   456   03-05-2019    AQ
   456   11-06-2019    AQ
   456   12-06-2019    AQ
   456   13-06-2019    AQ
   78    25-06-2019    AQ
   78    26-06-2019    AQ
   78    27-06-2019    AQ
   78    28-06-2019    AQ
```

For maximum and minimum date of each month of each unique id, the source should remain the same; for rest, it should change. The output should look something like this

```
   id    date       source
   456   01-05-2019    AQ
   456   02-05-2019    Data
   456   03-05-2019    AQ
   456   11-06-2019    AQ
   456   12-06-2019    Data
   456   13-06-2019    AQ
   78    25-06-2019    AQ
   78    26-06-2019    Data
   78    27-06-2019    Data
   78    28-06-2019    AQ
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow @Helly! Have a look at what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `transform` with `group by` to identify min max values

then use `.loc` to update source values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id": [456, 456, 456, 456, 456, 456, 78, 78, 78, 78], "date": [
    "01-05-2019", "02-05-2019", "03-05-2019", "11-06-2019",
    "12-06-2019", "13-06-2019", "25-06-2019", "26-06-2019",
    "27-06-2019", "28-06-2019"],
                        "source": ["AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ", "AQ"]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df['max_date'] = df.groupby(['id'])['date'].transform(max)
df['min_date'] = df.groupby(['id'])['date'].transform(min)

df.loc[df['max_date'] == df['date'], 'max_val'] = 1
df.loc[df['min_date'] == df['date'], 'min_val'] = 1
df.loc[(df['max_val'].notnull())|(df['min_val'].notnull()),'final_val']=1

df.loc[df['final_val'].isnull(),'source']='Data'
df.drop(['max_date','min_date','max_val','min_val','final_val'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
    id     date     source
0  456  2019-01-05     AQ
1  456  2019-02-05   Data
2  456  2019-03-05   Data
3  456  2019-11-06   Data
4  456  2019-12-06     AQ
5  456  2019-06-13   Data
6   78  2019-06-25     AQ
7   78  2019-06-26   Data
8   78  2019-06-27   Data
9   78  2019-06-28     AQ
```